# How to adjust the relationship line between tables when the position of tables are changed in pgAdmin4?

Tags: erd, pgadmin-4

I created two tables and built a foreign key between them, now I want to reorganize position of the tables in ERD (pgAdmin4 - version 6.14).

I'm **try** reorganize, but I cannot, see *image-01*:

[image: image-01:cannot change relationship lines]

My **expectation** is to align relationship line between tables like in *image-02* (ERD MySQL):

[image: image-02:expectation]